# How to can I run the OpenGeo Suite Community Edition under Apache Tomcat on Windows server 2003?

Tags: boundless-suite, tomcat

I have installed opengeo suite **community edition** on ubunutu 10.10 and it is working with apache tomcat and it all works great. So I decide to do the same on a Windows 2003 server at work.

*Note: On the windows 2003 server machine I already have apache tomcat installed and working correctly on port 8080*

So what I did was download the opengeo suite **community edition** for windows from [opengeo.org](http://opengeo.org/technology/suite/download/) and run the installer. I change the default port to 8081 and everything works fine! However it installs using a different web server (JBOSS?? or J something?), and this server only seems to operate when I am logged onto the the machine which is undesirable. For example I can't access geoexplorer from a remote machine unless I am also logged onto the server.

Has anyone got the openGeo suite **community edition** running with Tomcat? and how did you do it?

Thanks 
Ando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGeo products are released with Jetty webserver ( http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/ ). In your case, if you want to use tomcat, basically all web application modules in \webapps need to installed to tomcat webapps folder. I used to work with GeoServer as war file.

Comment: Ahhhh Jetty...the name had escaped me! Yeah I am currently working with GeoServer and GeoExplorer WAR files. However the GeoExplorer WAR file seems to be a little older than the GeoExplorer in the suite. Also I want to use the styler application as well. I'm not too good with server related stuff just yet, so I assume it's not as simple as copying the contents of opengeo webapps folder to my tomcat webapps folder?

Comment: I just installed community edition to see. As long as it bundled with Postgis DB and all data directories configured. It is not easy to go alone with tomcat. you definitely need Dashboard to start database and Jetty. But, if you could spend some time, you can depoly those webapps module to tomcat and use it too, extra effort required to set the configuration for paths. And database can be started with <installed_dir>bin/pg_start_server.cmd

Comment: I'm actually pulling my data from a previously established PostGIS DB on another server, so I don't use the PostGIS DB shipped with the quite.